# join using eloquent to not take common column from joined table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm joining two tables that both have tag_id (i.e. album.tag_id and photo.tag_id)

```
function GetJoined() 
{
    return Album::join('photos', 'photos.tag_id', '=', 'albums.tag_id')
}
```

but I don't want that resulting query to keep reminding me that this was a join from two tables

```
GetJoined()->where('tag_id', 1);
```

will be all like

```
'tag_id' in where clause is ambiguous
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't think you can. You'll have to specify the table `where('photos.tag_id')`. I don't think this is even possible in SQL. (Well maybe by using pointless subqueries)

Comment: You understand how ugly the code will be? I'll have to remember what the joined tables are and always add the "photos.tag_id". uggh.

Comment: Maybe you should look into [relationships](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#relationships) they have the potential to make your code less "ugly"

Comment: The question is, why you want this ugly method in the first place? Not mentioning that you have to remember anyway, since `getJoined` doesn't tell you much, so I don't think this is what you really wanted.